# json pattern about JacksonRepresentation with Restlet

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to the HTTP response json like this:

```
{
    "error": 
    {
        "code": "403",
        "message": "forbidden"
    }
}
```

My java class is:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "error")
public class ErrorResponse
{
    private String code = "";
    private String message = "";
}
```

I use the Restlet Jackson extension, How can I get the desired json?

I tried the following way:

```
return new ErrorResponse("123","testmsg");
return new JacksonRepresentation<ErrorResponse>(new ErrorResponse("123", "testmsg"));
```

Both doesn't work. The json doesn't contains the `error` part, only `code` and `message`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `return objectMapper.write().withRootName("error").writeAsString(new ErrorResponse());`

Comment: Thanks, it's an easy and clever way!

Comment: Agree. This is better than I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new object say, `ErrorResponseHolder` with field `error`.
2. Set `ErrorResponse` object to `error` field.
3. Return `ErrorResponseHolder`.